# encrypt / decrypt file

Tags: php, encryption

I have a need to encrypt and decrypt files using php. I need to have other users a preshared key to be able to decrypt the file. The encryption should be at the lease AES 128. Are there any good articles or tutorials on that
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple libraries, but the most common is probably mcrypt. A quick Google brings up a host of mcrypt tutorials, eg

http://www.itnewb.com/v/PHP-Encryption-Decryption-Using-the-MCrypt-Library-libmcrypt

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the application I sometimes use http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ because it is pure PHP (runs on every PHP server without needing any extensions).

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what your goal is.  Essential parts of the problem are:

- Key sharing.  How do you securely get the key to the user?
- Encryption.  How do you ensure the security of the key when encrypting the data?
- Problem.  You need to clearly state what problem that you expect encryption to solve.

Hopefully this will help you form new questions.